# How to apply QTread in python code (suspend GUI)

Tags: python, pyqt4, qthread

I'm tying applying QTread to my Python code. But unfortunately I'm doing something wrong, because GUI is suspended for few second after button click. What I'm doing wrong ?

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Window, self).__init__()
       #... some lines of code
    def home(self):
       self.convertclass = ConvertClass()
       btn_run = QtGui.QPushButton("Convert", self)
       self.convertclass.trigger.connect(self.convert)
       btn_run.clicked.connect(self.convertclass.convert)
       #... some lines of code
class ConvertClass(QtCore.QThread):
     def __init__(self):
        super(ConvertClass, self).__init__()
     def convert(self):
        #... some lines of code
```

Answer (score -1):

I take it you wish to have a long running process happen in the thread.

When you click the button is that when the thread should be started?
If so call the threads start() method.

Or are you starting the thread as a worker and sending work item to it
via a queue. In which case add the work item to queue when the button is pressed.

How will the GUI know the thread has completed its work in your application?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow why a comment and not an answer? Indeed until I answered enough questions stackoverflow bans new users from commenting.

Comment: yes, that is how it works unfortunately, you will need to get your rep-points up first. You could re-word this to be an answer to the original post.

Comment: Something like this ? `btn_run.clicked.connect(self.convertclass.start)`
Unfortunately after button click nothing happening